# Using Owin SessionStore for cookie storage still sends cookie to browser

Tags: c#, webforms, owin, stackexchange.redis

I have implemented cookie storage using Redis. I followed [this](https://github.com/chuongxl/Rhasta.Owin.Security.Cookies.Store.Redis) code example for the most part...

Nothing special about my Startup.Auth class:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    IDataProtector dataProtector = app.CreateDataProtector(typeof(RedisAuthenticationTicket).FullName);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,

        LoginPath = new PathString("/Login.aspx"),
        LogoutPath = new PathString("/Register.aspx"),
        SessionStore = new RedisSessionStore(new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector)),

        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        { 
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),

        }
    });
...
```

I was under the impression that implementing SessionStore would mean that the only session cookie i would see in the browser is ASPNET_SessionId, yet my app still seems to create a AspNetCookie after login... this is definitely coming from the Owin startup - i can change the name of it from within my startup.

[image]

My AuthenticationSessionStore class is firing away and grabbing the authentication cookie from Redis. I just can't figure out why this Cookie is still there and if it is there by design?

Comment: In the end sessions (in the server) are cookies in client(s) - except when you do things like "cookieless" where the "identifier" is in the url. The client still has to say to the server, "this is me, not anyone else".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit following the comments below*

The `.AspNet.Cookies` is the authentication cookie that allows the server to know when a user is logged in to your application.

The fact that you use Redis doesn't mean there's no need for a cookie anymore.
How could you differentiate users A and B if they didn't send cookies?

If you were not using Redis, the authentication cookie value would contain the user information.
When using Redis, the user information is stored there, and the authentication cookie value contains the Redis key that allows to access this information.

A session cookie is different from an athentication cookie in the sense that a user doesn't need to be logged in for you to store session data for them. This could be useful for, let's say, an ecommerce application where you show both unlogged and logged users which products they have looked at.

The same concept could apply to session: instead of storing that data in the cookie, you could decide to use an external store so that the amount of data that travels between the browser ad the server is minimal (only the session key).

---

*Original answer*

A cookie is still needed to identify the user.

The difference is that the cookie now no longer contains the session data, but only the Redis key that allows to access the session data.

Comment: I thought that was what the ASP.NET_SessionId was for?

Comment: My bad you're correct, but it's the same concept, in the sense that the authentication cookie now holds the key that contains the user information (the ClaimsPrincipal). How would you know a request comes from user A if there's no cookie?

Comment: I guess I was expecting it to use the ASP.NET_SessionId.  So this is all normal then?

Comment: It is all normal, you're correct. I updated my original answer to provide more information.